while running sqlmap in my terminal it showing me bash: python: command not found?
I cloned this tool sqlmap from GitHub in my debian 12 terminal using sudo apt.
with following steps

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap.git sqlmap-dev

there after a folder created in my home directory. I can see it in graphical user interface. thereafter I cd/ sqlmap-dev in terminal. when I was trying to run sqlmap commands it throwing me bash: python command not found. I'm providing below code please look into these issue.
david@debian:~$ cd sqlmap-dev
david@debian:~/sqlmap-dev$ python sqlmap.py -u "https://www.hacksplaining.com/lessons/sql-injection" --smart
bash: python: command not found
david@debian:~/sqlmap-dev$ python sqlmap.py -h
bash: python: command not found
david@debian:~/sqlmap-dev$

what went wrong with my installation of Sqlmap ?
Perhaps I missed to trying  python3 install sqlmap as it has python dependencies ? I don't know since there is git clone instruction. I just git cloned and started trying to run sqlmap through entering into directory cd/sqlmap-dev. then I tried to run sqlmap commands it throws me bash python command not found.

first thing you need to do is verify if you have python installed or not ?? if you can confirm that i can help you further. what is the output of  python -V or python3 --V"

david@debian:~$ which python3 /usr/bin/python3 david@debian:~$ python3  --version Python 3.11.2 

as your python is not in your path so please use the absolute path of your python installation to run sqlmap
cd sqlmap-dev
/usr/bin/python3 sqlmap.py -h

or if you want to setup your path just to use python3 sqlmap.py -h you need to add your path to .bashrc or .zshrc file, in your case probably .bashrc
nano ~/.bashrc

add this line at the end of the file
export PATH="/usr/bin/python3:$PATH"

and exit the nano editor with ctrl + x and y
apply the change by doing
source ~/.bashrc

or simply restarting the terminal
to verify path is correctly set use following command in the terminal :
echo $PATH

and you can simply use the short command python3 sqlmap.py -h  without absolute path. make sure you are inside the sqlmap-dev directory

successful. your solution worked. as you mentioned to add python3 to PATH, I added & checked to see whether it is working or not, it is working perfectly. `david@debian:~/sqlmap-dev$ python3 sqlmap.py -h
___
H
___ ["]__ ___ ___  {1.8.8.1#dev}
|_ -| . ["]     | .'| . |
||  [(]|||__,|  |
||V...       ||   https://sqlmap.org
Usage: python3 sqlmap.py [options]
Options:
-h, --help            Show basic help message and exit
-hh                   Show advanced help message and exit
`

This question can be now closed.  as I have followed all the steps & executed.  OP problem resolved.

It looks like you're either missing Python on your machine or it's Python 3.x that you have.
First try the following to ensure it's indeed the case:
python3 sqlmap.py -u "https://www.hacksplaining.com/lessons/sql-injection" --smart

If it still doesn't work then you'd have to install Python on your machine:
Run the following commands in a shell:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3

And for future convenience; ensure pip (package manager) is installed as well:
sudo apt install python3-pip

After running the following command, the following should work fine and sqlmap should be installed on your machine:
python3 sqlmap.py -u "https://www.hacksplaining.com/lessons/sql-injection" --smart


latest versions of both pip3 and python3 were installed.
david@debian:~$ pip3 --version pip 23.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.11) 
david@debian:~$ python3 --version Python 3.11.2 

i think OP already had python3 installed in machine as per his output in his comment

Then it seems it isn't added to the path. Should I update my answer or just set a pointer in there to answer of yours @nabinsademba, I am quite new here. Thank you.
